# Create a blank first column in kendo ui grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am new to kendo ui grid development.

I have a requirement where I want to display data in **kendo ui grid**.

I am able to bind the data to **kendo grid** using **java-script**.

This is how I did it.

```
(document.getElementById(divId)).kendoGrid({
            columns: cols,
            dataSource: data,           
            change: onChange,
            selectable: "multiple",
            //selectable: "multiple cell",
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "ID"
                }
            }
        }).data("kendoGrid");
```

The data is displayed in the grid.

Now, I want to create a blank first column in the grid that will display a image. How can I do this. The grid is bound to data dynamically. I have not specified any hard coded columns. All columns are created dynamically.

Please anyone can tell me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to explicitly define the columns because:

1. You want to add a columns that is not in the model.
2. The content of the column is an image that is not a KendoUI basic type that can be inferred from the model definition.

Said so, you have to add a column that is something like:

```
var cols = [
    // Your other columns
    ...
    {
        title :"Image",
        template: "<img src='my_image.gif'/>"
    },
    // More columns
    ...
];
```

In addition you might need to use an image that is not a constant but depending on the content of a column. Then you might do:

```
var cols = [
    // Your other columns
    ...
    {
        title: "Status",
        template: "# if (status) { # <img src='ok.gif'/> # } else { # <img src='nak.gif'/> # } #"
    },
    {
        title   : "Photo",
        template: "<img src='#= image #'/>"
    }
    // More columns
    ...
];
```

Where depending on the value of field in your model called `status` I display the image `ok.gif` or `nak.gif`. Or directly use the content of the field `image` for generating the URL to the image being displayed.

Check [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/templates/overview) for an overview on KendoUI templates.

Comment: Thanks OnaBai for quick reply. surely will try on this. Just had a question how can I set the title for grid but should not be visible. What actually I want is on the click of the newly created column as mentioned above, I want to get some additional values which will be common for entire grid. So how can I set any additional/custom property and access it. Also it would be very helpful if I can set title for grid but should not be visible. Only I need to access its value. Again thanks for the reply.

Comment: I've seen that you posted a question on click on the image. Please, see my answer there. Regards.